# Find image on screen

Tags: c++, winapi

I wonder how to solve this problem. I want to check every X seconds if the screen contains an image (for example a red dot) and if so return True. I am very familiar with Python, and there are some easy solutions there. But I haven't found a similar solution yet.

What I basically want to do is:

1. Take a screenshot
2. Locate image X on the screenshot
3. Return bool

Looked into OpenCV and would be possible to solve it that way, but might be a bit overextending. I was thinking about getPixel to loop over all the pixels in the screen. But it's extremely slow.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HWND runelite = GetForegroundWindow();
    HMONITOR monitor = MonitorFromWindow(runelite, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);
    MONITORINFO info;
    info.cbSize = sizeof(MONITORINFO);
    GetMonitorInfo(monitor, &info);
    int monitor_width = info.rcMonitor.right - info.rcMonitor.left;
    int monitor_height = info.rcMonitor.bottom - info.rcMonitor.top;

    int r, g, b;

    HDC screenshot = GetDC(NULL); 

    for (int i = 0; i < monitor_height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < monitor_width; j++) {
            DWORD color = GetPixel(screenshot, j, i);
            cout << "Scanning -> X: " << j << " Y: " << i << endl;
            r = GetRValue(color);
            g = GetGValue(color);
            b = GetBValue(color);
            if (r == 0 && g == 0 && b == 0) {
                cout << "Button found by color!" << endl;
                goto end;
            }
        }
    }

    end:
    ReleaseDC(NULL, screenshot);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: >I am very familiar with Python, and there are some easy solutions in there. In that case, you could just write a solution in Python and [embed it into your C++ program](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html).

Comment: Why using `goto` while Loops make it easy to understand and more readable?

Answer (score 4):

you could greatly increase the speed if you copy your `HDC`s content to another bitmap and get a pointer to the image data and loop over this.

create a memory bitmap

```
HDC memDC = CreateCompatibleDC ( hDC );
HBITMAP memBM = CreateCompatibleBitmap ( hDC, nWidth, nHeight );
SelectObject ( memDC, memBM );
```

then bitblt the screen data to that bitmap via `BitBlt` and get the bitmap data with `GetDIBits`.

please also note, that `GetDC(NULL)` does not make a screenshot, but gets you access to windows live main HDC. drawing to it directly draws on the desktop. 
Thatswhy every `GetPixel` on it does take quite long.

Comment: `GetDIBits()` makes another unneccessary copy though. Instead, create a device-independent bitmap using `CreateDIBSection()` to get direct access to the pixel buffer of the bitmap.